# cannot find symbol error when adding onReceivedSslError

Tags: java, android, ssl, webview

I have a java class

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{ 
 private MyUIWebView webView;


@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
{
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

}
```

This compiles well.to which I want to add SSL error handling too, so I add

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed();
}
```

But this produces compile error

```
build:
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/admin/Documents/Mine
[javac] /Users/admin/Documents/MyWebViewClient.java:62: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class SslErrorHandler
[javac]     public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
[javac]
```

I have includes in place for this class

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

```
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
    import android.net.http.SslError;
```

Looks like those two classes are missing imports.

Comment: I did try that, but it only gave another error, this time for symbol  : class SslError

Comment: import android.net.http.SslError; produces an error : cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SslError
    [javac] location: package android.net.http

Comment: its only available since Android API Level 8. What version are you trying this on?

Comment: well..kind of new to Android, using ant to build something I downloaded. how can I tell ? and is there a solution to handle SSL errors with API prior to Level 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add ");" after last } There are en mistcake in example you use