# Get rid of SSL verification in Cordova in app browser

Tags: cordova, ssl, https, inappbrowser

I am building a web and hybrid mobile app. The apps communicate with third party service using  ssl self-sign cert in staging env. Desktop browsers allow to accept invalid cert with **risk** warning but in iOS app I got this error

```html
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "xxx" which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

I understand the risk but as my third party provider can not provide valid ssl cert for the service in staging server so I have no choice.

Is there any configs/possibilities to allow invalid ssl cert in iOS and android inappbrowser plugin.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you solve that problem, I also face same problem .Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **iOS** will always complain about invalid certificates, either in debug or release mode. To avoid this you should place the following code at the end of the AppDelegate.m file.
>
> ```
> @implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
> + (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
> {
>     return YES;
> }
> @end
> ```
>
> For Cordova users this file is placed in
>
> ```
> project/platforms/ios/Project/Classes/AppDelegate.m
> ```
>
> **Android (Cordova specific)**
>
> In Android the history is different. It will allow you to make requests to services with invalid certificates, but only if the app is compiled in build mode. On the other hand, when you would build the app in release mode (ie: to send the APK to a co-worker or stuff like that), the Cordova Web View, which is where the HTML + CSS + JS you wrote runs, will not allow you to make “insecure” requests. Once again, to avoid this you should modify a platform file. In this case the file will be CordovaWebViewClient.java
>
> You would need to modify a method in the mentioned filed, like this:
>
> ```
> public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
>   final String packageName = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
>   final PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
>
>   ApplicationInfo appInfo;
>   try {
>     appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
>     if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
>       // debug = true
>       handler.proceed();
>       return;
>     } else {
>       // debug = false
>       // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO CHANGE:
>       // 1. COMMENT THIS LINE
>       // super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
>       // 2. ADD THESE TWO LINES
>       // ---->
>       handler.proceed();
>       return;
>       // <----
>     }
>   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
>     // When it doubt, lock it out!
>     super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **This file is placed in (Cordova v4 and below)**
>
> ```
> project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java
> ```
>
> **In newer versions of Cordova (v5 and later) the file is now placed in**
>
> ```
> project/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java
> ```

and

> **You should not use these solutions for production apps. This is just to test them or share them with co-workers.**

Reference: [Ignoring invalid SSL certificates on Cordova for Android and iOS](http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/)

Comment: In cordova-android@6.3.0 this solution still works, check my answer below.

Comment: This does not work for capacitor anymore. see answer by @Abdul Fatir

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @Levi Murray.

For Capacitor 2.2.0, you need to tweak @Levi Murray answer.

**Android** - node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/BridgeWebViewClient.java

Add the override method with the other methods.

```
    ....
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
      handler.proceed();
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Worked for Capacitor 3 as well :)

Answer (score 5):

#### Here's what worked for me using Capacitor

**Note**: *I am changing dependency files, but I was only using this for development purposes as all of our development servers were using a different domain name (that we didn't own at the time) from our live domain name.*

> **Android** - node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/src/main/java/com/getcapacitor/Bridge.java
>
> Find the existing `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {...});` line. Line 207 for me.
>
> ```java
>    // Line #207
>    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
>        // Add this override method
>        @Override
>        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, >SslError error) {
>            handler.proceed();
>            return;
>        }
>        ...
>    }
> ```
>
> **iOS** - Pods/Development Pods/Capacitor/CAPBridgeViewController.swift
>
> ```swift
>    // Line #204
>    // Add this public class method to the CAPBridgeViewController
>    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
>        let cred = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
>        completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
>    }
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much . its working great in ionic capacitor.

Comment: Don't forget import statements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6958986/45311

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up a https proxy for that staging server. Your app contact the https://proxy_to_staging_server.yourdomain.com with a valid certificate and proxy_to_staging_server.yourdomain.com make a back-end request to the real staging server and replicate the anwser

Answer (score 0):

In **cordova-android@6.3.0** (and newer?) edit **SystemWebViewClient.java** and edit the `onReceivedSslError` as shown in the uppercase comments:

```java
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

        final String packageName = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
        final PackageManager pm = parentEngine.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();

        ApplicationInfo appInfo;
        try {
            appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
                // debug = true
                handler.proceed();
                return;
            } else {
                // debug = false
                // ADD THESE LINES TO IGNORE INVALID SSL CERTIFICATE
                handler.proceed();
                return;
                // COMMENT THIS LINE:
                //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // When it doubt, lock it out!
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    }
```

Now SSL certificate errors will be ignored in both Debug and Release configurations.

This was taken from one of the answers in [this article](https://www.andreszsogon.com/common-apache-cordova-build-errors-with-visual-studio/).